# Best method to parse data logged in a serial manner instead of as tabular, json etc?

Tags: bash, awk, text-processing, text-parsing

I have a group of log files, all formatted basically like this example (file1.text):

```
================================================
Running taskId=[updateFieldInTbl]
startTime: 16:03:34,580
------------------------------------------------
INFO:DBExecute: SQL=[       UPDATE tbl set field = value where thing > 0; ]

SQL: UPDATE tbl set field = value where thing > 0
Statement affected [746664] rows.
------------------------------------------------
Finished taskId=[updateFieldInTbl]
endTime: 16:06:30,571
elapsed: 00:02:55,991
failure: false
anyFailure: false
================================================
================================================
Running taskId=[calculateChecksum]
startTime: 16:06:30,571
------------------------------------------------
INFO:DBExecute: SQL=[       update tbl set checksum = MD5(CONCAT_WS('',field, field2, field3));     ]

SQL: update tbl set checksum = MD5(CONCAT_WS('',field, field2, field3)); 
Statement affected [9608630] rows.
================================================
=====  Greater than 5 minutes Review! ==========
================================================
------------------------------------------------
Finished taskId=[calculateChecksum]
endTime: 16:44:04,473
elapsed: 00:37:33,901
failure: false
anyFailure: false
================================================
================================================
Running taskId=[deleteMatchingChecksum]
startTime: 16:44:04,473
------------------------------------------------
INFO:DBExecute: SQL=[       delete tbl from tbl inner join other on tbl.checksum = other.checksum;  ]

SQL: delete tbl from tbl inner join other on tbl.checksum = other.checksum;
Statement affected [9276213] rows.
================================================
=====  Greater than 5 minutes Review! ==========
================================================
------------------------------------------------
Finished taskId=[deleteMatchingChecksum]
endTime: 17:49:26,817
elapsed: 01:05:22,344
failure: false
anyFailure: false
================================================
================================================
Running taskId=[deletemissinguserDataChecksum]
startTime: 17:49:26,817
------------------------------------------------
INFO:DBExecute: SQL=[       delete from tbl          where  some_id =0;  ]

SQL: delete from tbl          where  some_id =0;
Statement affected [0] rows.
------------------------------------------------
Finished taskId=[deletemissinguserDataChecksum]
endTime: 17:49:26,847
elapsed: 00:00:00,030
failure: false
anyFailure: false
================================================
```

I'd like to convert each of these to look something like this:

```
file1 | taskId | startTime | endTime | elapsed | rowsAffected | Info | failure | anyFailure
file1 | updateFieldInTbl | 16:03:34 | 16:06:20 | 00:02:55 | 746664 | SQL=[       UPDATE tbl set field = value where thing > 0; ] | false | false
file1 | calculateChecksum | 16:06:30 | 16:44:04 | 00:37:33 | 9608630 | SQL=[       update tbl set checksum = MD5(CONCAT_WS('',field, field2, field3));     ] | false | false
file1 | deleteMatchingChecksum | 16:44:04 | 17:49:26 | 01:05:22 | 9276213 | SQL=[       delete tbl from tbl inner join other on tbl.checksum = other.checksum;  ] | false | false
```

Generally, I'd just start out the system doing the logging into a database table so the logs were already in a format that was easy to work with, but that is not an option at this moment, so I have to parse the existing logs into something resembling useful.

What tool(s) would you recommend? I think the goal is to build something using a bash script if possible. Any guidance on how to go about building the parser would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: explain why have `rowsAffected` value been missed from your output? Also, add some more output representative lines

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest rowsAffected missing was my oversight. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest **`Awk`** processing:

```
awk 'NR==1{ 
         fn=substr(FILENAME,0,length(FILENAME)-5); 
         print fn" | taskId | startTime | endTime | elapsed | rowsAffected | Info | failure | anyFailure" 
     }
     /Running taskId/{ gsub(/^.+=\[|\]$/, ""); taskId=$0 }
     /startTime:/{ sub(/,.*/,"",$2); startTime=$2 }
     /INFO:/{ sub(/^INFO:DBExecute: /,""); info=$0 }
     / affected/{ gsub(/\[|\]/,"",$3); affected=$3 }
     /endTime/{ sub(/,.*/,"",$2); endTime=$2 }
     /elapsed/{ sub(/,.*/,"",$2); elapsed=$2 }
     /^failure/{ fail=$2 }
     /anyFailure/{ 
         printf "%s | %s | %s | %s | %s | %d | %s | %s | %s\n", 
                 fn, taskId, startTime, endTime, elapsed, affected, info, fail, $2 
     }' file1.text
```

The output:

```
file1 | taskId | startTime | endTime | elapsed | rowsAffected | Info | failure | anyFailure
file1 | updateFieldInTbl | 16:03:34 | 16:06:30 | 00:02:55 | 746664 | SQL=[       UPDATE tbl set field = value where thing > 0; ] | false | false
file1 | calculateChecksum | 16:06:30 | 16:44:04 | 00:37:33 | 9608630 | SQL=[       update tbl set checksum = MD5(CONCAT_WS('',field, field2, field3));     ] | false | false
file1 | deleteMatchingChecksum | 16:44:04 | 17:49:26 | 01:05:22 | 9276213 | SQL=[       delete tbl from tbl inner join other on tbl.checksum = other.checksum;  ] | false | false
file1 | deletemissinguserDataChecksum | 17:49:26 | 17:49:26 | 00:00:00 | 0 | SQL=[       delete from tbl          where  some_id =0;  ] | false | false
```

Comment: Holy Crap! I wish I could upvote this many times! Now I really want to learn awk.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I'd avoid using specific field names as much as possible, there's no need to test for all of the values since most of the input lines follow the same format so just single out the couple of lines that DON'T follow the common format:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }

!NF || /^([^[:alpha:]]|SQL|Finished)/ { next }

{ tag = val = $0 }

/^Running/ {
    prt()
    gsub(/^[^ ]+ |=.*/,"",tag)
    gsub(/.*\[|\].*/,"",val)
}

/^Statement/ {
    tag = "rowsAffected"
    gsub(/.*\[|\].*/,"",val)
}

/^[:[:alpha:]]+: / {
    sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/^[:[:alpha:]]+: /,"",val)
}

{
    tags[++numTags] = tag
    tag2val[tag] = val
}

END { prt() }

function prt( tag,val,tagNr) {
    if (numTags > 0) {
        if ( ++recNr == 1 ) {
            printf "\"%s\"%s", "file", OFS
            for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
                tag = tags[tagNr]
                printf "\"%s\"%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
            }
        }
        printf "\"%s\"%s", FILENAME, OFS
        for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
            tag = tags[tagNr]
            val = tag2val[tag]
            gsub(/"/,"\"\"",val)
            printf "\"%s\"%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
    delete tags
    delete tag2val
    numTags = 0
}
```

I'd also output it as CSV so you can read it into Excel or do whatever else you like with it:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1
"file","taskId","startTime","INFO","rowsAffected","endTime","elapsed","failure","anyFailure"
"file1","updateFieldInTbl","16:03:34,580","SQL=[       UPDATE tbl set field = value where thing > 0; ]","746664","16:06:30,571","00:02:55,991","false","false"
"file1","calculateChecksum","16:06:30,571","SQL=[       update tbl set checksum = MD5(CONCAT_WS('',field, field2, field3));     ]","9608630","16:44:04,473","00:37:33,901","false","false"
"file1","deleteMatchingChecksum","16:44:04,473","SQL=[       delete tbl from tbl inner join other on tbl.checksum = other.checksum;  ]","9276213","17:49:26,817","01:05:22,344","false","false"
"file1","deletemissinguserDataChecksum","17:49:26,817","SQL=[       delete from tbl          where  some_id =0;  ]","0","17:49:26,847","00:00:00,030","false","false"
```

If you really care about the order you can trivially tweak it to output the field values by their specific tags instead of numeric order.

Comment: How does your program know that its reached the END and therefore should call `prt()`? From what I can tell, END would be reached every time `next` is called from your `IF` check at the top??

Comment: No, that's not how awk works. the stuff in `BEGIN{...}` is called before the file is opened, the stuff in `END{...}` is called once the end of file has been reached, and everything in between is called once for every line of input by awks implicit "while read $0" work loop. `next` just says "go to the next line of input", kinda like a break in a loop. GNU awk has a `nextfile` statement that means "stop processing the current input file and start processing the next one if present" - maybe that's what you're thinking of.

Comment: Its more accurate to say that I was speaking from knowing nothing about `awk`. Thanks for clarifying.